# Go Back Button in a text adventure game in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a text adventure game with a tutorial and I want to have some changes. I want to add a 'go back' button that would take me one step back.

I have some textNodes, and it works like this:

```
function showTextNode(textNodeIndex) {
  const textNode = textNodes.find(textNode => textNode.id === textNodeIndex)
  textElement.innerText = textNode.text
  while (optionButtonsElement.firstChild) {
    optionButtonsElement.removeChild(optionButtonsElement.firstChild)
  }

  textNode.options.forEach(option => {
    if (showOption(option)) {
      const button = document.createElement('button')
      button.innerText = option.text
      button.classList.add('button')
      button.addEventListener('click', () => selectOption(option))
      optionButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
    }
  })
}
```

And all of my textNodes have id's, texts and options. If the id is lower than 0, this happens:

```
function selectOption(option) {
  const nextTextNodeId = option.nextText
  if (nextTextNodeId <= 0) {
    return startGame()
  }
  state = Object.assign(state, option.setState)
  showTextNode(nextTextNodeId)
}

function startGame() {
  state = {}
  showTextNode(1)
}
```

And you die and game restarts. I thought if I have an additional node, and lead players to that node on click of Go Back button, it might work since all id's are unique and I can work with those. So I tried to have a similar function like:

```
function selectOption(option) {
  const nextTextNodeId = option.nextText
  if (nextTextNodeId = 10) {
    return goBack()
  }
  state = Object.assign(state, option.setState)
  showTextNode(nextTextNodeId)
}
function goBack() {
 state = {}
 showTextNode(textNode.id = textNode.id -1)
}
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea how can I make a lastTextNodeId instead of nextTextNodeId?

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it?  Are you getting an error on the browser's development console?  When you use the browser's script debugger, what specifically fails?  Did you define a second function called `selectOption`, or did you change the existing one?  It's not really clear.

Comment: Firstly I tired having an onclick function like this: <button class="goBack" onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button> and goBack function was the same as it is in the question. Most of the time the console said 

Uncaught ReferenceError: textNode is not defined
    at goBack (game.js:16:16)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:97:71)

I also tried to change restart function, but later I couldn't find a method to set the players textNode as I want.

Comment: Well, `textNode` indeed is not defined within the scope of that function.  That's what the error is telling you.  The only `textNode` variable defined here is within the scope of the `showTextNode` function.